# MySql - Inner Join returning rows beyond specified date range

Tags: mysql

Please see the below and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c98c57/1

The query is used to return the min and max prices within 0 to 180 days (last 6 months). It does do the job. However, if the prices are found in other rows, beyond or within the desired range, it joins it too the dataset...

I just need it to return, for reach report_term... 
i.e. January 2018 ...
February 2018 ...

On LIVE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2eMu.png)

Thanks

```
select   a.metal_price_datetime
         , t1.highest_gold_price
         , t1.report_term
         , t2.lowest_gold_price
         ,t2.metal_price_datetime

  from metal_prices_v2 a
  inner join (
      SELECT  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(metal_price_datetime), ' ', YEAR(metal_price_datetime)) AS report_term
               , max(metal_price) as highest_gold_price

      from metal_prices_v2
      WHERE metal_id = 1
      AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), metal_price_datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 180
      GROUP BY report_term
  ) t1 on t1.highest_gold_price = a.metal_price
  inner join (
     select   a.metal_price_datetime
         , t.lowest_gold_price
         , t.report_term

  from metal_prices_v2 a
  inner join (
      SELECT  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(metal_price_datetime), ' ', YEAR(metal_price_datetime)) AS report_term
               , min(metal_price) as lowest_gold_price

      from metal_prices_v2
      WHERE metal_id = 1
      AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), metal_price_datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 180
      GROUP BY report_term
  ) t on t.lowest_gold_price = a.metal_price

 ) t2 on t2.report_term = t1.report_term
```

Comment: Shouldn't the datediff evaluation occur in the where clause for both table aliases? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f501b/8/0  but maybe I don't understand the problem yet.

Comment: It helped..... however, i have added more data to this, please see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c98c57/1    notice how some report terms have high or low date times not in the corresponding period (report_term)....  i can add group by report_term at the bottom, but still the same problem...

Comment: even GROUP BY report_term will solve it but on live DB, it is still has low price date times from August 08.. or high date times from August 08

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2eMu.png

Comment: Total rewrite/refactoring but something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c98c57/52/0?  I've generated two data sets: one for low price one for high price per report term.  I'm still unsure what denotes the "report term" something and I may not be handling edge cases of different metals correctly. but if you always filter by a single metal then those edge cases will not matter.

Comment: @xQbert  nice. seems to work on the fiddle, but when running on my DB, i get : #1054 - Unknown column 'lowP.Report_Term' in 'on clause'  i dont understand i straight copy paste the code...   case insensitive clause? as when i changed lowP.Report_Term to lowP.report_term, it worked but then error-ed again:- lowP.RN column not found.. and this is where i stopped...

Comment: can you put as an anwser too, i will accept it... as it looks like a perfect answer. incredible.